Failing to enable a wifi adapter "RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error"
I have dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10 set up however my wireless network adapter seems to be disabled when using Ubuntu despite working fine with windows.
Output of: lshw -C Network
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: enp6s0
   version: 15
   serial: 18:31:bf:6d:1b:51
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:30 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7704000-f7704fff memory:f7700000-f7703fff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: 00
   serial: 00:0c:43:01:31:1c
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic firmware=0.40 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:36 memory:f7600000-f760ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 6
   bus info: usb@1:3
   logical name: enx261cafd196df
   serial: 26:1c:af:d1:96:df
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.239.55 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair

When trying to execute sudo ip link set wlp7s0 up
I get RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error
Here are the full results from running the suggested diagnostic script: Results
I have tried sudo sed -i 's/WirelessEnabled=false/WirelessEnabled=true/' /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state which helped by showing the wifi networks that are available however I could not connect to them and they disappeared few seconds after using that command. The results of lshw -C Network are still the same.
Any ideas how to resolve this? Also as a side note I'm very new to linux so I'd appreciate a step by step solution.

This question is similar to: My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@waltinator, I have run the diagnostic script mentioned in the answers of that question, that being said the question itself has nothing that provides a clear solution.

Try running the script again and post the new result, the first was not complete

@Jeremy31 I've edited the question with updated results, I`ve accidentally haven't copied the entire txt file

Try sudo sed -i 's/WirelessEnabled=false/WirelessEnabled=true/' /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
